# Change default sorting on Google Analytics' Dashboard page

Tags: google-analytics, sorting

We have implemented Google Analytics (GA) for our website and ended up creating 25 dashboards. The issue is every time I go to the Customisation => Dashboards on GA, it shows the dashboards sorted by creation date by default.

Is there a way we could change the default to sort it by the name of the dashboard instead?

I have seen a [post on changing the default date range for dashboards using JavaScript](http://www.currybet.net/cbet_blog/2007/06/quickly-setting-the-default-go.php). Maybe something similar can be used here.

[image: Sorted by "Named"]